# POI setRepeatingRows using different row than specified

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using apche POI library to parse through a multi-sheet excell document.

I am using `sheet.setRepeatingRows()` for page titles, the problem I am having is that `sheet.setReapeatingRow(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("1:1"))` is repeating the 2nd row, i have tried: 0:0, 0:1 and got a NullPointerExceptions. Short of creating another row above my first, is there a way to repeat the first row?

Comment: Do you use XSSF or HSSF? Do you have a small code sample which shows how you are trying to use it?

Comment: Im using xssf, and the snippet in the question is the exact use I have. However I believe I just solved this by setting manually setting title rows to none.

Comment: Please note that you give Excel-row-numbers, which are 1-based. So using 0 for the first row is not correct here.

For me using "1:1" correctly sets the first row in the Excel file as repeating row. 

So it seems there is some other problem, maybe you can add some more of your code to let us see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, believe my second row was set as the title row, deselected that and all works find now.